# Is there another way to say "something has no more to do with something, than something"?

Tags: meaning

Is there another way to say "something has no more to do with something, than something"?

> Marx emphasized that ‘since exchange-value is a definite social manner of expressing the amount of labor bestowed upon an object, Nature **has no more to do with it, than** it has in fixing the course of exchange ... so far no chemist has ever discovered exchange-value either in a pearl or a diamond.

Comment: Where is that text from, please? It doesn't seem to be googleable. It seems to be saying simply that valuation is a social phenomenon, not a physical property, which is true but trivial.

Comment: Please add at least attribution to the quotation, if not a link to the source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The specific question

The following was the specific question:

> Is there another way to say "something has no more to do with something, than something"?

---

Let's start with a different example:

> **Yellow paint** has ***no more*** to do with **the study of geriatrics** than it has to do with **turning on a TV**.

The sentence can also be expressed symbolically:

> **A** has ***no more*** to do with **X** than it has to do with **Y**.

---

### The normally assumed meaning

Most often, this is interpreted in the sense that A has little to do with X or Y:

> **Yellow paint** has ***equally little*** to do with **the study of geriatrics** and **turning on a TV**.

However, the fact it doesn't have much to do with either of those things is really understood from context.

---

### The literal meaning

The *literal* meaning of the sentence is simply that A doesn't have ***more*** to do with X than it has to do with Y.

In other words, the following could also be true:

> **Health** has ***no more*** to do with **the study of geriatrics** than it has to do with **the study of pediatrics**.

Health actually has ***a lot*** to do with both of those things, but what the sentence is actually saying is this:

> **Health's involvement** in **the study of geriatrics** is not greater than its involvement in **the study of pediatrics**.

This can also be expressed symbolically:

> **A's involvement** in **X** ≤ its involvement in **Y**.

---

### The example sentence in the question

The same analysis can be applied to the example sentence in the question, assuming I'm parsing it correctly:

> **Nature** has ***no more*** to do with **the amount of labour bestowed upon an object** than it has to do with **fixing the course of exchange**.

As per the above, this can be rephrased in two different ways.

- The common interpretation:
  **Nature** has ***equally little*** to do with **the amount of labour bestowed upon an object** and **fixing the course of exchange**.
- The literal interpretation:
  **Nature's involvement** in **the amount of labour bestowed upon an object** is not greater than it's involvement in **fixing the course of exchange**.

Answer (score 0):

"X has no more to do with Y than with Z" means that X has no effect on either Y or Z.  Normally, Z is something that everyone would agree that X has no effect on, and Y is a more arguable case.